# What is the best way to have some control in the middle of a page to consume remaining verticle space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently my methodology to solve the following problem would be to calculate and adjust the extra space using JavaScript. Is there a better (CSS/HTML)'ish way?

I calculate the used space and subtract the available space. Then change the control's height to that value. Works great, but is there a CSS solution?

This is all better illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/sdh38gxe/4/

```
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="divForHeight">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Some contols" />
            <textarea>I want to expand this to have the maximum verticle space without introducing scrollbars</textarea>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Some more contols" />
            <button type="button">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I realized that the answer I want is not as simple as this, but what I'm looking for is some css properity such as `height: consumeMaximumAvailableSpace;` or perhaps if I used divs as tables?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you could use the CSS layout feature called flex box. This layout can grow or shrink depending on both the vertical and horizontal space available and can relayout the items it contains based on rules you specify. You can see more about flex box here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. This arises because body percentage widths are based on browser window, but percentage heights are based on document size, which might be less or more than the browser window.

The only resolution is the one you have taken, to use js.